# Depth first search not returning correct object type

Tags: python, algorithm, search

I have the following code that traverses a tree object, but I can't get it to return the node object when the key is found. it gives me NoneType instead. the objects are simple and included below.

```
class StructureTree:
    def __init__(self, issueID, depth):
        self.issueID = issueID
        self.depth = depth
        self.children = []
        self.worklog_data_rows = []
        self.structure_data_row = [] #contains issue data for any issue found in the global structure


    def addChild(self, elem):
        self.children += [elem]

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<%d : %d>" % (self.issueID, self.depth)


class StructureForest:
    def __init__(self):

        self.trees = []
        self.roots =[]

    def addRoot(self, root):
        self.roots += [root]

def DFS(node, key):
'''
Depth First Traversal (In-order).
@node -- int
@key -- int
'''
    if node.issueID == key:
        print "Found!"
        return node
    else:
        for child in node.children:
            print "here"
            return DFS(child, key)


def search_node(n_tree_forest, key):
'''
Traverses entire forest.
@key -- int
'''
    for root in n_tree_forest.roots:
       val = DFS(root, key)
       return val
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Answer (score 0):

You never return a value either in the main function or in any of the recursive steps. Both times you call `DFS` you need to do `return DFS(..., ...)`.

Comment: edited my algorithm in the question, but that still gives me the same result.

Comment: Well, the other issue is you're not checking to see if you actually found anything from the recursive call before returning again.

Comment: yes, but I'm passing in a value that I know should return a node when I'm testing the function

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think I see the issue doesn't look like you are returning anything when you go into the else statement which you have to do for proper recursion.  Modify your DFS method...

```
def DFS(node, key):

    if node.issueID == key:
        print "Found!"
        return node.issueID
    else:
        for child in node.children:
            print "here"
            val = DFS(child, key)
            if val: return val
         return False
```